# break a href link event

Tags: javascript, function, href, confirm

I search a method to break the process after click a html a element. It is possible to make a `onclick="alert();"` event on this a element and the process is temporary stopped, till the OK button is clicked, or the process is breaked, when the page are reloaded or click previous page. Also the break is, but not perfect. With a `confirm()` it is similare, but by clicking "Cancel" the process is not canceled.

```js
function myFunction() {
  var confirmresult = confirm("Press a button!");
  if (confirmresult === true) {
    // OK = go away!
  } else {
    // Cancel = stay here!
  }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<a href="https://www.example.com" onclick="myFunction()" target="_blank" rel="nofollow">example.com</a>
</body>
</html>
```

The example don't work by me. Here the code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<a href="https://www.example.com" onclick="myFunction()" target="_blank" rel="nofollow">example.com</a>
<script>
function myFunction() {
  var confirmresult = confirm("Press a button!");
  if (confirmresult === true) {
    // OK = go away!
  } else {
    // Cancel = stay here!
  }
}
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: If you're not actually going to change locations, then don't use an `<a>` element. Use a `<button>` instead. Anchors semantically indicate a change of location. Buttons semantically indicate some action happening on the current page.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to display a confirmation dialog when clicking an <a> link?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10462839/how-to-display-a-confirmation-dialog-when-clicking-an-a-link)

Comment: That said, `event.preventDefault()` is how you stop a native HTML element from doing something. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/preventDefault

Comment: also: [Display confirmation popup with JavaScript upon clicking on a link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/293648/display-confirmation-popup-with-javascript-upon-clicking-on-a-link) @Josh this functionality is semantic and built into the language, the link is still a link, it just has a condition applied to it.

Comment: Can you please post an example with `event.preventDefault()`? I don't understand it. A a href is a JS event?

Comment: @pilchard @Josh OK. Thanks. It is possible that the `preventDefault()` methode only works with `addEventListener`? I have testet it with `onclick="myFunction()"` and it don't works. I needed it with `onclick="myFunction()"` why this is already exist.

Comment: ah, ok, not `this` but `event`. Thats new for me.

Comment: @Malama, you have to pass `event` as a parameter for `event.preventDefault()` to work. For example: `onclick="myFunction(event)"`. I prefer event listeners, but onclick works okay.

Answer (score -1):

I have found a solution, but im not secure is it valide. Pleas help!

There is not so easy why the people think.

The thing is, it should be a solution for existing websites. No new coding is needed. Only insert the `function myFunction()`. `onclick="myFunction()" is always present`. And its only possible to put JS code in the `head` (not in the footer), because for this a custom `<script>` is always loaded via PHP in the webpages.

**First**, a methode with only code a new `function` with **javascript:void(0);**

The running code snippet function here don't work by me. Below a JSFiddle.

```js
function myFunction() {
  var confirmresult = confirm("Press a button!");
  if (confirmresult === true) {
    // OK = go away!
  } else {
    // Cancel = stay here!
    document.getElementById("demo").removeAttribute("target");
    document.getElementById("demo").href = "javascript:void(0);";
  }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<a id="demo" href="https://www.example.com" onclick="myFunction()" target="_blank" rel="nofollow">example.com</a>
</body>
</html>
```

The code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<a id="demo" href="https://www.example.com" onclick="myFunction()" target="_blank" rel="nofollow">example.com</a>
<script>
function myFunction() {
  var confirmresult = confirm("Press a button!");
  if (confirmresult === true) {
    // OK = go away!
  } else {
    // Cancel = stay here!
    document.getElementById("demo").removeAttribute("target");
    document.getElementById("demo").href = "javascript:void(0);";
  }
}
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/dLp8qtcm/

**Second**, a solution with **preventDefault()**. Consider the `event` instead a `this`. For this a edit of the webpages is needed for inside the `event` in `onclick="myFunction(event)"`.

Thanks for the hints with the `preventDefault()`, but the examples in the answers don't work by me. Here is a working solution.

The running code snippet function here don't work by me. Below a JSFiddle.

```js
function myFunction(e) {
  var confirmresult = confirm("Press a button!");
  if (confirmresult == true) {
    // OK = go away!
  } else {
    // Cancel = stay here!
      e.preventDefault();
  }
};
```

```html
<a href="https://www.example.com" onclick="myFunction(event)" target="_blank" rel="nofollow">example.com</a>
```

```
<a href="https://www.example.com" onclick="myFunction(event)" target="_blank" rel="nofollow">example.com</a>
<script>
function myFunction(e) {
  var confirmresult = confirm("Press a button!");
  if (confirmresult == true) {
    // OK = go away!
  } else {
    // Cancel = stay here!
    e.preventDefault();
  }
};
</script>
```

JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/osanthdq/

EDIT: The matter is a little bit complex. I have explained it here: [Event keyword in js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4968194/event-keyword-in-js/74744358#74744358)

Comment: Did you try the [suggestion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74735962/break-a-href-link-event#comment131902427_74735962) by @pilchard?
`<a href="https://www.example.com" onclick="return confirm('Press a button!')" target="_blank" rel="nofollow">example.com</a>`

Comment: Thanks, but puh ... , that's not so easy for me with JS code in the `onclick=""`. The website is always running and have a `onclick="myfunction()"`. With a simple search and replace i can modifying it to one of the solution above. But, the `onclick="myFunction(event)"` is always not so easy, because the `event`. ... i must think about it ...

Comment: ... its a little bit complex. A modificable `<script>` is always inside the head and loaded via PHP. It is also a separate file that can easy edited with untouch the website code. Its not always so simple how the people think. ;)